# Why is Brace expansion with variables not working as expected?

Tags: bash, variable, brace-expansion

I would like to set a variable (x=100) in the brackets such as

```
x=100    
for i in {0.."$x"..50} ;do
echo $i 
done
```

the desire output for i should be

```
0
50
100
```

although I get as an output

```
{0..100..50}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That simply is not possible in `bash`. If you see the [order of expansions in `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), the variable expansion, happens at a latter time than the time the shell expands the brace `{0..50}`. So at the time of brace expansion, the shell sees the construct as `{0..$x..50}` which would be an invalid construct to expand.

You need an alternate way to this, best way would be a `for` loop in `bash` arithmetic context.

```
for ((i=0; i<=100; i+=50)); do 
    printf "%d\n" "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

That syntax would work in zsh (where it comes from) or ksh93 or `yash -o braceexpand`, but not in `bash` where you can't use expansions within `{x..y}`. But here, it would be better to use ksh93-style `for ((...))` loops anyway:

```
x=100    
for ((i = 0; i <= x; i += 50)) {
  printf '%s\n' "$i"
}
```